# Power Pivot - Aggregate within groups to determine max value

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I'm looking for a DAX formula (for Power Pivot) that aggregates within certain groups and across other groups to determine the maximum.

Here's my data table:

| State | Customer | Fruit | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY | A | Apple | 5 |
| NY | A | Orange | 1 |
| NY | A | Pear | 5 |
| NY | B | Apple | 1 |
| NY | B | Orange | 6 |
| NY | C | Apple | 2 |
| NY | C | Orange | 2 |
| NY | C | Pear | 5 |
| CA | D | Orange | 4 |
| CA | D | Pear | 2 |

I want to determine the most popular fruit by `State` (ignoring `Customer`). In NY, there are a total of 8 apples, 9 oranges, and 10 pears. So the formula should return `Pear`.

Resulting in a table like this:

| State | Dominant Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| NY | Pear |
| CA | Orange |

What is the Power Pivot formula I need for that `Dominant Fruit` column on the resulting table? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a measure to rank the amount of fruits per state like so:

```
Ranking = RANKX( ALLEXCEPT( 'Table','Table'[Customer],'Table'[State] ) , CALCULATE( SUM( 'Table'[Qty] ) ) )
```

This measure will rank "Dominant Fruit" (based on the quantity) with 1.
[image: Ranking table]

You can than add filter on visual to show only values where rank is 1:

[image: final result]